# Location Services Stop working after reinstall with iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, ios10

Location services stopped working after I uninstalled my iOS10 app. I have the description set up in the Info.plist so it confuses me why location services would stop working. The app does not show up in Settings->Privacy->Location Services

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs to use your location so that it may send it to your selected contacts.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs to use your location so that it may send it to your selected contacts.</string>
```

Checking for status using the following code reveals that the status is Not Determined.

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
        NSLog(@"RESTRICTED");
    } else if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSLog(@"DENIED");
    } else if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        NSLog(@"NOT DETERMINED");
    } else if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
        NSLog(@"ALWAYS");
    } else if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        NSLog(@"WHEN IN USE");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The viewController viewDidLoad method contains the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
            NSLog(@"RESTRICTED");
        } else if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
            NSLog(@"DENIED");
        } else if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
            NSLog(@"NOT DETERMINED");
        } else if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
            NSLog(@"ALWAYS");
        } else if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
            NSLog(@"WHEN IN USE");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[yourLocationManager startUpdatingLocation]` which will prompt the alert for Using location.

Until then `authorizationStatus` will be `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`

**Edit**

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]; 
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
```

Add this

Comment: I run [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; when a button is pressed, but it does not work or ask the user for permission. I have the following in viewDid Load: self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; self.locationManager.delegate = self; and didUpdateToLocation does not get triggered.

Comment: Have you added [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]  or [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] ?

Comment: [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;

Comment: just realized in my above comment that I initialized the view controller before requesting authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check authorization status, and if it's xxx, you need to call `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` or `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`. That will trigger an alert to the user.

If you've deleted the app by long-pressing the app icon and tapping the X, that revokes the user's permission to use location services, so the app will be denied access until you call `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` or `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` again.